# Two vertical aligned minipages are horizontally shifted

Tags: listings, minipage

I want to align two listings next to each other using minipages. Unfortuanately the right minipage is shifted a little bit to the bottom. What's the problem here?

```
\documentclass[11pt,fleqn,a4paper,pdftex,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{parcolumns}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstdefinestyle{customc}{
    language=C,
    tabsize=2,
    breaklines=true,
    captionpos=b,
    frame=tlrb
}
\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{minipage}{.48\textwidth}
    \begin{lstlisting}[style=customc, caption={Unoptimized if statement in GetFilteredNewHostCommand}]
if (tmp != NULL)
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.48\textwidth}
    \begin{lstlisting}[style=customc, caption={Optimized if statement in GetFilteredNewHostCommand}]
if (unlikely(tmp != NULL))
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you complete your code example? It should be directly compilable. This way, others can just copy it, see what's the problem, modify what needs to be modified and show you the solution with another compilable code.

Comment: Try to add to  `minipage` position option `t`: `\begin{minipage}[t]{.48\textwidth}

Comment: The default [c] aligns the centers, which are in fact aligned.

Comment: thanks that solved the problem! @John Kormylo I don't understand why the centers are aligned. What are the centers?

Comment: Ah I understand now. The caption is part of the listing which is part of the minipage so the center is relativ to the actual code and the caption